# Firefox for Mac OS X 'remember logins' not saved on exit

Tags: mac, firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm using Firefox 53.0.2 (64-bit) on Mac OS X "Sierra" (10.12.3).

I can set the "Security->Remember logins for sites" for the duration of a single run of Firefox, and it works as expected.

But the setting is not stored across execution of Firefox.  After an exit and restart, I have to go to settings and re-select 'remember logins'.

And I do not have anything set that I know of that would cause Firefox to 'forget' items from the current session on restart.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting signon.rememberSignons to true in about:config? This setting is saved as: 
user_pref("signon.rememberSignons", true); 
in file prefs.js in Firefox profile directory:
/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/profilename

Comment: Are you asking questions here or writing an answer?

Comment: Thank you, that is the sort of thing I'm looking for.  Unfortunately, everything I've done (in browser with about:config, in editor directly on prefs.js) to set it to 'true' gets reverted to false.  I noticed there is also a "user_pref("signon.importedFromSqlite", true);", so there could be a value stored in an SQLite file that is overriding the prefs.js setting.  Would setting this to "false" keep the rememberSignons from changing?

Comment: And answered my own question:  no, it didn't have any effect.  So two possibilities:  1) the setting from SQLite is overriding my change; 2) something else is affecting this.  The second is more likely, because the value for the SQLite setting was reset to 'true' after I had set it to 'false'.  One more item is there's a setting called "services.sync.prefs.sync.signon.rememberSignons" which implies something could be forcing a sync from some other place.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just to be sure check about:preferences#sync if Preferences are selected for sync. You can also install Firefox Developer Edition for comparison, it does not interfere with regular Firefox.